# html css video как изменить размер непропорционально?

Tags: html, css, видео, width, height

Есть элемент видео:

```
<video>
 <source src="URL">
</video>
```

У него доступно изменение ширины и высоты. Но они изменяются пропорционально, т.е. если изменить ширину, то высота измениться, даже если ей задано фиксированное значение. Как изменять размеры непропорционально через css ?

Comment: можно попробовать растягивать видео с помощью transform: scaleX(n); где n - коэффициент растяжения

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!